Using a CSV to set "fill" for SVG circles
I have SVG code that I would like to modify (with JavaScript?). I could use some help figuring out how to change the circles, as shown in the picture below, in accordance with values from a spreadsheet (CSV, or otherwise). The map (you may be able to guess why) will be changing almost daily; that is why I would like to use JavaScript to change it.

I have 4 code snippets here, only 2 of which are at issue: the data loader/parser and the JS modifer.
I included a truncated version of the SVG for clarity's sake as well as the gatsby-config.js, in case you need to see plugins.


This snippet is where I tried to read in and parse the data for use in a JS script.
// src/utils/useCsvData.js
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

const useCsvData = () => {
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query {
      allStateProjCsv {
        nodes {
          state
          color
          tooltip
        }
      }
    }
  `);
  return data.allStateProjCsv.nodes;
};

export default useCsvData;

This is the file that is supposed to modify the "fill" and all for a tooltip to appear when the circle is hover over.
// src/components/ECProjection.js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import useCsvData from '../utils/useCsvData';
import ECProjection from '../graphics/united_states.svg';
import { select } from 'd3';

const ElectoralCollegeProjection= ({ svgContent }) => {
  const data = useCsvData();

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const svg = select('svg');
    data.forEach(({ state, color, tooltip }) => {
      const circle = svg.select(`#${state}`);
      circle.attr('fill', color)
            .attr('data-tooltip', tooltip);
    });

    svg.selectAll('circle')
       .on('mouseover', function (event) {
         const tooltipText = select(this).attr('data-tooltip');
         // Show tooltip with tooltipText
       })
       .on('mouseout', function () {
         // Hide tooltip
       });
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <ECProjection />
  );
};

export default ECProjection;

This is a snapshot of the SVG, just in case that is helpful or relevant.
//SVG
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 930 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="100%" height="100%">

<g class="state">

  <path class="al" d="m 643,467.4 .4,-7.3 -.9,-1.2 -1.7,-.7 -2.5,-2.8 .5,-2.9 48.8,-5.1 -.7,-2.2 -1.5,-1.5 -.5,-1.4 .6,-6.3 -2.4,-5.7 .5,-2.6 .3,-3.7 2.2,-3.8 -.2,-1.1 -1.7,-1 v -3.2 l -1.8,-1.9 -2.9,-6.1 -12.9,-45.8 -45.7,4 1.3,2 -1.3,67 4.4,33.2 .9,-.5 1.3,.1 .6,.4 .8,-.1 2,-3.8 v -2.3 l 1.1,-1.1 1.4,.5 3.4,6.4 v .9 l -3.3,2.2 3.5,-.4 4.9,-1.6 z">
  <title>Alabama</title></path>

</g>

<g class="statecircle">
  <circle id="al-circle" class="al" cx="650" cy="412" r="18" fill="#BF1D29"></circle>
  <text class="al-text" x="650" y="412" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="white">AL</text>
</g>

And the gatsby-config.js
// gatsby-config.js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-transformer-csv`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        path: `${__dirname}/src/data/`,
        name: `data`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-image`, //These four probably aren't relevant to our question here
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`, // But, including just to show they are there
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    'gatsby-transformer-remark',
  ],
}

I can prepare the CSV in whatever way you would need me to; the data is handled over in R. It can be "state id, hex code, tooltip text." This is sorta my first rodeo with JS, so that probably shows.

It's a bit unclear where the code is failing. You mentioned there are issues with both the data loader/parser and the JS modifier. If you console.log(data) inside the ECProjection component, are you getting the data as expected?

@thompsonsj Good thinking. It is saying the following: "(0 , _utils_useCsvData__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default) is not a function." And it is pointing to this line in the component, "const data = useCsvData();" which I imagine has something to do with an error relating to the other file itself.

I see that in your SVG excerpt you have circle with ID #${state}-circle, but in your code you are selecting #${state}.

@Mr.Hedgehog Wow. Good catch haha, that solved it.

I was able to do some ChatGPT wizardry to solve the tooltip problem. Thanks to all three of you for your help!

I'm not sure it is possible to modify a svg file. However since you're using React you could create a component with your svg code and then you'd be able to modify it like you would with any HTML.
I don't know React so here is an exemple using vanilla JS. I've added an input of type range to simulate the change in value for the radius of the circle.


const alCircle = document.getElementById('al-circle');
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', evt => {
    alCircle.setAttribute('r', evt.target.value);
})
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 930 600" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" width="100%" height="100%">

<g class="state">

  <path class="al" d="m 643,467.4 .4,-7.3 -.9,-1.2 -1.7,-.7 -2.5,-2.8 .5,-2.9 48.8,-5.1 -.7,-2.2 -1.5,-1.5 -.5,-1.4 .6,-6.3 -2.4,-5.7 .5,-2.6 .3,-3.7 2.2,-3.8 -.2,-1.1 -1.7,-1 v -3.2 l -1.8,-1.9 -2.9,-6.1 -12.9,-45.8 -45.7,4 1.3,2 -1.3,67 4.4,33.2 .9,-.5 1.3,.1 .6,.4 .8,-.1 2,-3.8 v -2.3 l 1.1,-1.1 1.4,.5 3.4,6.4 v .9 l -3.3,2.2 3.5,-.4 4.9,-1.6 z">
  <title>Alabama</title></path>

</g>

<g class="statecircle">
  <circle id="al-circle" class="al" cx="650" cy="412" r="18" fill="#BF1D29"></circle>
  <text class="al-text" x="650" y="412" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle" fill="white">AL</text>
  
</g>

<hr>
<input type="range" id="input" min="5" max="60" value="18">



